# Laravel. Why we should need the API token and also session? Why not just only session?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

in Introduction of authentication :

> At its core, Laravel's authentication facilities are made up of
>   "guards" and "providers". Guards define how users are authenticated
>   for each request. For example, Laravel ships with a session guard
>   which maintains state using session storage and cookies and a token
>   guard, which authenticates users using a "API token" that is passed
>   with each request.

I do not understand why we should need the `CSRF-TOKEN` cookie and also the `laravel_session` cookie?

Why should one is not enough ?

After all, laravel change the value of the cookies on each request

so I can not understand why we need them both ?

Comment: For increasing the security we use session and API is just the way to deal with that!

Comment: But they both do the same thing!
If I use one of them it is less secure? why?

Comment: this might help you http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication thanks